# Transform the schema of a spark data-frame in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input data-frame:

```
{ 
  "C_1" : "A",
  "C_2" : "B",
  "C_3" : [ 
            {
              "ID" : "ID1",
              "C3_C2" : "V1",
              "C3_C3" : "V2"
            },
            {
              "ID" : "ID2",
              "C3_C2" : "V3",
              "C3_C3" : "V4"
            },
            {
              "ID" : "ID3",
              "C3_C2" : "V4",
              "C3_C3" : "V5"
            },
            ..
          ]
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{ 
  "C_1" : "A",
  "C_2" : "B",
  "ID1" : {
              "C3_C2" : "V2",
              "C3_C3" : "V3"
          },
  "ID2" : {
              "C3_C2" : "V2",
              "C3_C3" : "V3"
          },
  "ID3" : {
              "C3_C2" : "V4",
              "C3_C3" : "V5"
          },
  ..
}
```

`C_3` is an array of `n` structs with each item having a unique `ID`. The new data-frame is expected to convert the `n` structs in `C_3` into separate columns and name the columns as per the value of `ID`.

I am new to Spark & Scala. Any thought on how of achieve this transformation will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode the structs, then pivot by ID:

```
val df2 = df.selectExpr("C_1","C_2","inline(C_3)")
            .groupBy("C_1","C_2")
            .pivot("ID")
            .agg(first(struct("C3_C2","C3_C3")))

df2.show
+---+---+--------+--------+--------+
|C_1|C_2|     ID1|     ID2|     ID3|
+---+---+--------+--------+--------+
|  A|  B|[V1, V2]|[V3, V4]|[V4, V5]|
+---+---+--------+--------+--------+

df2.printSchema
root
 |-- C_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C_2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ID1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C3_C2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C3_C3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ID2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C3_C2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C3_C3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ID3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C3_C2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- C3_C3: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. This works like a charm but my df has a lot of columns and this(`groupBy("C_1","C_2", .. "C_N")`) is very expensive and out of scope for my use-case.
      
Do you know if it is possible to use a udf like `flatFunction(col("C_3"))` which will process the array and return the desired output?

Comment: @Swas_99 do you know the number of columns in the output, before you do the query?

Comment: yes number of col in df is static but number of elements in `C_3` is dynamic. If having static elements in C_3 will help, I can try to experiment with that at least.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify my question. Do you know the number of ID's before you do the query?

Comment: Number of IDs is static now but subject to change. If I can have a more optimised solution to support fixed IDs now (say `ID1` &  `ID2`) and later modify the code to add more IDs, then that could also be helpful for my use-case.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not too sure how to do this without a pivot... the main problem is extracting the ID's from structs and put them as column names, which is difficult to do even with UDFs. Usually this requires pivot. Maybe it's worth opening another question to ask other experts... :)

Answer (score 0):

[posting my hacky solution for reference].
@mck's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66758582/1744480) is probably the neat way to do it but it wasn't sufficient for my use-case. My data-frame had a lot of columns and using all of them on `group-by` then pivot was an expensive operation.
For my use-case, the `IDs` in `C_3` were unique and known values, hence this is the assumption made in this solution.
I was able to achieve the transformation as follows:

```
case class C3_Interm_Struct(C3_C2: String, C3_C3: String)
case class C3_Out_Struct(ID1: C3_Interm_Struct, ID2: C3_Interm_Struct) //Manually add fields as required

val custom_flat_func = udf((a: Seq[Row]) =>
    {
        var _id1: C3_Interm_Struct= null;
        var _id2: C3_Interm_Struct = null;
        for(item<-a)
        {
            val intermData = C3_Interm_Struct(item(1).toString, item(2).toString)

            if(item(0).equals("ID1")) {
                _id1 = intermData
            }
            else if(item(0).equals("ID2")) {
                _id2 = intermData
            }
            else if()//Manual expansion
                ..
        }

        Seq(C3_Out_Struct(_id1, _id2)) //Return type has to be Seq
    }
)

val flatDf = df.withColumn("C_3", custom_flat_func($"C_3")).selectExpr("C_1", "C_2", "inline(C_3)") //Expand the Seq which has only 1 Row
flatDf.first.prettyJson
```

Output:

```
{ 
  "C_1" : "A",
  "C_2" : "B",
  "ID1" : {
              "C3_C2" : "V2",
              "C3_C3" : "V3"
          },
  "ID2" : {
              "C3_C2" : "V2",
              "C3_C3" : "V3"
          }
}
```

`udf`s are generally slow but this is much faster than `pivot` with `group-by`.

[There may be more efficient solutions possible, I am not aware of them at the time of writing this]